# Importing a makefile inside Eclipse - symbols could not be resolved

Tags: eclipse, build, makefile

I'm trying to import an existing project into Eclipse. I did the following steps:
- I downloaded the source from a repository.
- I ran ./autogen.sh
- I ran ./configure
- I selected Makefile Project with Existing Code from Eclipse File menu

The class files are now grouped by type (.h and .cpp) and I can reach .cpp from .h by pressing ctrl+Tab and vice versa. 
When I press Build, the building starts and works fine. If I put syntax errors inside a file the make returns an error.

However Eclipse's intellisense reports many error like "Function snprintf could not be resolved", and "Symbol 'NULL' could not be resolved". 
How can I hide/resolve these errors? Was my import procedure incomplete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `/usr/include` to the path (see http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm) or tune the Discovery options (http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_newproj_discovery_options.htm?cp=11_4_6_8_2_2)

Comment: danke sir! I've always problems finding the place where to put include path in Eclipse, as at work I use Visual Studio ;-)

Comment: bitte sehr, und viel Glück